# Can't install cargo-tree: couldn't determine visual studio generator

Tags: windows, rust

I'm trying to install cargo-tree on my Windows machine. It uses Windows 10, Visual Studio build tools 15. This is my active rustup toolchain:

```
active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.26.0 (a77568041 2018-05-07)
```

When running `cargo install cargo-tree`, the build fails. The build log ends with:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `libssh2-sys v0.2.7`
process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\NICOLA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installt7F5FM\release\build\libssh2-sys-726b9e90a2ed2b95\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
thread 'main' panicked at '

couldn't determine visual studio generator
if VisualStudio is installed, however, consider running the appropriate vcvars script before building this crate
', C:\Users\nicolas-delsaux\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.31\src\lib.rs:552:25
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `cargo-tree v0.18.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\NICOLA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installt7F5FM`
```

According to some documentation I found on the web, it seems to be related to some `vcvars` script to invoke, and an older Visual Studio version to install. I don't fully understand what to do so

- Should I install an older version of Visual Studio?
- Do I have some script to run?

Comment: In the start menu search for `developer command prompt` and try to execute your command from that console. That handles the `vcvars` for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to @user25064, this requires installing the command through developer command prompt (and, more specifically, the developer command prompt for your architecture - take attention to x86/x64 architectures)